# Error: Permission denied when trying to create database django

Tags: django, postgresql, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to create a database for a django project and I'm getting the following error:

> (blog-venv)vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/django_projects/microblog$
>   createdb microblog createdb: database creation failed: ERROR: 
>   permission denied to create database

I'm working in a vagrant/virtualbox environment.

Please help.

thanks.

Comment: provide what you have done so far (code)

Comment: Are you postgres user when running that command?

Answer (score 13):

solved the issue by making sure I had superuser permissions.

=> ALTER USER myusername CREATEDB